# Regular Expression to fetch vertical offset from CSS

Tags: php, regex

I have been fiddling with this for almost an hour and am getting nowhere. Regexes are not my strong suit.

I have data like the following:

```
.cke_button_about .cke_icon { background-position: 0 -76px; }
.cke_button_maximize .cke_icon { background-position: 0 -108px; }
```

I need to replace the vertical values (-76px and -108px) using `preg_replace_callback()`. The callback function is written, but I can't for the life of me get the numbers out properly.

This works fine for 4-digit numbers:

```
preg_replace_callback("/(background\-position\:)(.*)(\d{4})(px)/", "recalculate",
$css_string);
```

but how can I make it so it recognizes any kind of number? {1-4} should work but somehow conflicts with the first, horizontal value.

Would anybody like to help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/(background\-position\:)(\D*\d*\D*)(\d+)(px)/
```

Gets what you want while preserving the current capturing groupings.

Answer (score 3):

`((-?)[0-9.]+)` would probably be better, this would match the following cases:

- 1.0
- 1000
- -400
- 642.42
- -642.42
- 0

The whole code would be something like this:

```
preg_replace_callback("/(background\-position\:)(.*?)((-?)[0-9.]+)(px)/", "recalculate",
$css_string);
```

Comment: Wouldn't the (.*) select the '?' any way?

Comment: Though if you are going to think about the `-`, you'll need to replace the `.*` with `.*?` or `[^-]*`.

Comment: @Chalkey, it would, but I don't think it should? I would like the regex to extract the full number, including sign if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do `(background\-position)(.*)([0-9]+)(px)`?

Answer (score 0):

what about `preg_replace_callback("/(background\-position\:)\s*(\d+)\s+(\d{4})(px)/", "recalculate",
$css_string);`? `+` meaning "one or more"